# RDLC VS2010 Adjust the height of a text-box corresponding to the font-size

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc, rdl

When I design a RDLC-Report and change the FontSize of a text-box to a smaller value, the height of the text-box is not adjusted automatically. If I try then to adjust the height manually, it's very difficult to find the right height.

Is there a simple possibility to adjust the height corresponding to the font size (in the designer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the grid spacing, Report + Report Properties, General tab, Grid spacing.  The default setting is 0.125 inch, 4 points.  With the "Snap to Grid" check box turned on, only font sizes that are a multiple of 4 are easy.  If you try, say, a font of 10 points (not a multiple of 4) then you'll have a hard time sizing the text box.